# ImageSlider problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-slider

I'm working on creating a ImageSlider but my images are shown as following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6veNd.jpg)
I know that is something wrong in the slider elements style but don't get it. I'm new to implementing sliders on web pages. If someone have an idea let me know, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
const slideStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  borderRadius: "2rem",
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  backgroundPosition: "center",
};

const rightArrowStyles = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  transform: "translate(0, -50%)",
  right: "32px",
  fontSize: "45px",
  color: "#fff",
  zIndex: 1,
  cursor: "pointer",
};

const leftArrowStyles = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  transform: "translate(0, -50%)",
  left: "32px",
  fontSize: "45px",
  color: "#fff",
  zIndex: 1,
  cursor: "pointer",
};

const sliderStyles = {
  position: "relative",
  height: "100%",
};

const dotsContainerStyles = {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
};

const dotStyle = {
  margin: "0 0.2rem",
  cursor: "pointer",
  fontSize: "1rem",
};

const slidesContainerStyles = {
  display: "flex",
  height: "100%",
  transition: "transform ease-out 0.3s",
};

const slidesContainerOverflowStyles = {
  width: "",
  overflow: "hidden",
  height: "100%",
};

const ImageSlider = ({ slides, parentWidth }) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const goToPrevious = () => {
    setCurrentIndex(
      (currentIndex) =>
        (((currentIndex - 1) % slides.length) + slides.length) % slides.length
    );
  };
  const goToNext = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentIndex) => (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length);
  };
  const goToSlide = (slideIndex) => {
    setCurrentIndex(slideIndex);
  };

  const getSlideStylesWithBackground = (slideIndex) => ({
    ...slideStyles,
    width: `${parentWidth}px`,
    backgroundImage: `url(${slides[slideIndex].url})`,
  });
  const getSlidesContainerStylesWithWidth = () => ({
    ...slidesContainerStyles,
    width: `${parentWidth * slides.length}px`,
    transform: `translateX(${-(
      Math.min(currentIndex, slides.length - 2) * parentWidth
    )}px)`,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer(setInterval(goToNext, 2000));

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [slides]);

  return (
    <div style={sliderStyles}>
      <div>
        <div onClick={goToPrevious} style={leftArrowStyles}>
          ❰
        </div>
        <div onClick={goToNext} style={rightArrowStyles}>
          ❱
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* here to modify */}
      <div style={slidesContainerOverflowStyles}>
        <div style={getSlidesContainerStylesWithWidth()}>
          {slides.map((_, slideIndex) => (
            <div
              key={slideIndex}
              style={getSlideStylesWithBackground(slideIndex)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* stop here */}
      <div style={dotsContainerStyles}>
        {slides.map((_, slideIndex) => (
          <div
            key={slideIndex}
            style={dotStyle}
            onClick={() => goToSlide(slideIndex)}
          >
            ●
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

I tried to modify the dimensions of the div that holds the slider but it didn't worked.

Comment: I know they say a picture is worth a thousand words, but in this case you should really describe what is wrong in words as well.  The picture does *not* say it all, I'm afraid.  Perhaps you want only one image visible?  Perhaps you want it centered?  The size of your content doesn't match the size of the container, so it seems reasonable to me that you may intentionally want multiple image visible.  Also, don't be afraid to change _enter image description here_ to something descriptive.  Accessibility is a real thing.

Comment: Ok, got it :)) sooo the problem is that I want a single centered image on that slider and yes the sizes are not matching is right but I don't know where to modify and how, all my selected images are 1920x1080 and if I modify the image size it distroy the aspect ratio of it.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just state that you have issues. Put all information (including responses to comments) _in your question_, not down here.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77572439/edit) your question to add information relevant to your question.  Such information shouldn't be just a comment on your own question.